# Unstable accuracy and val_accuracy, plus, lower test accuracy when using transfer learning. (DenseNet121 as it's used in many X-ray systems)

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, classification, transfer-learning

I just tried to train model to predict pneumonia on data set: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/paultimothymooney/chest-xray-pneumonia

Here is what I did:

First of all, I tried to equalize the quantity of Normal and Pneumonia images in a copy-paste way:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9Ehu.png)

Than i used augmentation:

```
    train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                                      samplewise_center=True, 
                                      samplewise_std_normalization=True, 
                                      horizontal_flip = True,
                                      zoom_range=0.1, 
                                      height_shift_range=0.05, 
                                      width_shift_range=0.05,
                                      rotation_range=5) 
    
    test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
    val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255., validation_split=0.5)
    
    train_gen = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory=input + 'train', 
    #color_mode = 'grayscale',
    target_size=(img_dims, img_dims), 
    batch_size=batch_size, 
    class_mode='binary', 
    shuffle=True)

    test_gen = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory=input +'test',
    #color_mode = 'grayscale', 
    target_size=(img_dims, img_dims), 
    batch_size=batch_size, 
    class_mode='binary', 
    shuffle=True)


    val_gen = val_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory=input + 'test',
    #color_mode = 'grayscale',
    target_size=(img_dims, img_dims), 
    batch_size=batch_size, 
    class_mode='binary', 
    shuffle=True
    )
```

As I need high accuracy, I have not constructed own CNN, but used Transfer learning:

```
#####
from tensorflow.keras.applications.densenet import DenseNet121

base_model = tf.keras.applications.DenseNet121(input_shape=(img_dims, img_dims, 3),
                                               include_top=False,
                                               weights='imagenet')

x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.L1L2(l1=1e-5, l2=1e-4))(x)
x = Dropout(0.4)(x)
x = Dense(512, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.L1L2(l1=1e-5, l2=1e-4))(x)
x = Dropout(0.3)(x)
x = Dense(64, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.L1L2(l1=1e-5, l2=1e-4))(x)
x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
predictions = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)


model_doc = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)


for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False


model_doc.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='best_weights_DenseNet_121.h5', monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='min')
earlystop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=4, verbose=1, mode='min')
reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.1, patience=3, verbose=1, mode='min', min_lr=0.00001)

history = model_doc.fit(           
           train_gen,
           steps_per_epoch=train_gen.samples // batch_size, 
           epochs=20, 
           validation_data=val_gen,
           validation_steps=val_gen.samples // batch_size,
           callbacks=[checkpoint, earlystop, reduce_lr])
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dTOx.png)

As it is shown, here is overfitting. But I tried to load weigths from 1 epoch and it gave me the accuracy on test-data too low:

```
scores = model_doc.evaluate(test_data, test_labels, verbose=0)
print("Test accuracy: %.2f%%" % (scores[1]*100))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJHRv.png)

Then I continue by using fine tuning:

```
base_model.trainable = True

#freeze 10 layers

for layer in base_model.layers[-10:]:
    layer.trainable = True

#lower lr
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-5)

model_doc.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer = opt,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='best_weights_DenseNet_121_fine_tuned.h5', monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='min')
earlystop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=4, verbose=1, mode='min')
reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.1, patience=3, verbose=1, mode='min', min_lr=0.000001)

history_fine = model_doc.fit(
                         train_gen, 
                         steps_per_epoch=train_gen.samples // batch_size, 
                         epochs=30, 
                         validation_data=val_gen, 
                         validation_steps=val_gen.samples // batch_size,
                         shuffle=True,
                         callbacks=[checkpoint, earlystop, reduce_lr])
```

And I got the accuracy raising but val_accuracy going up and down:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcQy9.png)

I've tried to make classifier simplier, sj leave there Dense(512...) + Dropout(0.3) + Dense(1...), reduce and raise learning rate, tried to work with "raw" data from Kaggle (means leave without copy-paste prep before training), tried to use calss_weights in fitting etc. - All I got is overfitting.

Any please suggest me what is going here wrong.

Thanks in advance.